# PHP preg_replace: Replace all anchor tags in text with their href value with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all anchor tags within a text with their href value, but my pattern does not work right.

```
$str = 'This is a text with multiple anchor tags. This is the first one: <a href="https://www.link1.com/" title="Link 1">Link 1</a> and this one the second: <a href="https://www.link2.com/" title="Link 2">Link 2</a> after that a lot of other text. And here the 3rd one: <a href="https://www.link3.com/" title="Link 3">Link 3</a> Some other text.';
$test = preg_replace("/<a\s.+href=['|\"]([^\"\']*)['|\"].*>[^<]*<\/a>/i",'\1', $str);
echo $test;
```

At the end the text should look like this:

```
This is a text with multiple anchor tags. This is the first one: https://www.link1.com/ and this one the second: https://www.link2.com/ after that a lot of other text. And here the 3rd one: https://www.link3.com/ Some other text.
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you *really* want to try and [parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ... are you sure? Have you drawn a pentagram in a circle around your desk as a precaution first?

Comment: @CD001 If there is a better, simpler solution I would be very thankful to hear it.

Comment: Safer would be to use a DOM Parser; HTML isn't regular so attempting to parse it with Regular Expressions often leads to problems - which is pretty much what the link I posted states... but with a lot more style, class and humour ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't.

Use a parser instead.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// since you have a fragment, wrap it in a <body>
$dom->loadHTML("<body>".$str."</body>");
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
while($link = $links[0]) {
    $link->parentNode->insertBefore(new DOMText($link->getAttribute("href")),$link);
    $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}
$result = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
// remove <body>..</body> wrapper
$output = substr($result, strlen("<body>"), -strlen("</body>"));
```

[Demo on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/7Wgqn)

Comment: [The DOMDocument approach performs slightly better over the Regexp one](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/5416e776bf6b1f2152ee).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler perhaps not, but safer is to loop the string with strpos to find and cut the string and remove the html.

```
$str = 'This is a text with multiple anchor tags. This is the first one: <a class="funky-style" href="https://www.link1.com/" title="Link 1">Link 1</a> and this one the second: <a href="https://www.link2.com/" title="Link 2">Link 2</a> after that a lot of other text. And here the 3rd one: <a href="https://www.link3.com/" title="Link 3">Link 3</a> Some other text.';

$pos = strpos($str, '<a');

while($pos !== false){
    // Find start of html and remove up to link (<a href=")
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . substr($str, strpos($str, 'href="', $pos)+6);
    // Find end of link and remove that.(" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>)
    $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str,'"', $pos)) . substr($str, strpos($str, '</a>', $pos)+4);
    // Find next link if possible
    $pos = strpos($str, '<a');
}
echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/vdN7E

Edited to handle different order of a a-tag.

Comment: Unless there happens to be something like `<a class="funky-style" href="URI" ... />` ... there's no restriction on attribute order so ...

Comment: @CD001 looking at OPs own regex it seems he wants to remove all href links and just keep a link as text. If that is not the case then OP should edit with a better example. Edit: I see now what you mean. Yes, but again a better example then

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still set on regex, this should work:

```
preg_replace("/<a\s+href=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^\>]*>[^<]+<\/a>/i",'$1', $str);
```

But you're probably better off with a solution like what Andreas posted.

FYI: the reason your previous regex didn't work was this little number:

```
.*>
```

Because `.` selects everything you ended up matching everything past the url to be replaced; all the way to the end.  This is why it appeared to only select and replace the first anchor tag it found and cut off the rest.

Changing that to

```
[^\>]*
```

Ensures that this particular selection is constrained to only the portion of the string which exists between the url and the ending bracket of the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a tags with href values you can do:

```
$post = preg_replace("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","$1",$post);
```

If you want to replace with text values:

```
$post = preg_replace("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","$2",$post);
```